# Algorithm: get suggestions of IPV6 addresses based on CIDR segment and keyword?

Tags: typescript, algorithm, ip-address, ipv6, cidr

Get specific `size` count of ipv6 addresses which including specific `keyword` and inside specific [cidr](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/CIDR)

```
function getIpAddresses(cidr: string, size: number, keyword: string): string[] {
  // ...
}
```

`input` and `output` demo:

```
getIpAddresses('fd00:100:64::/64', 10, '1011')

// =>

[
  'fd00:100:64:::::1011',
  'fd00:100:64::::1:1011',
  'fd00:100:64::::2:1011',
  'fd00:100:64::::3:1011',
  'fd00:100:64::::4:1011',
  'fd00:100:64::::5:1011',
  'fd00:100:64::::6:1011',
  'fd00:100:64::::7:1011',
  'fd00:100:64::::8:1011',
  'fd00:100:64::::9:1011'
]
```

Related npm package [ip-address](https://github.com/beaugunderson/ip-address)

The following implementation is extremely slow (taking about 13s to run for such a simple example):

```
import { Address6 } from "ip-address";
import { BigInteger } from "jsbn";

const shortIpV6Address = (ipV6Address: string) =>
  ipV6Address
    .split(":")
    .map((item) => item.replace(/^0+/, ""))
    .join(":");

export const getIpAddresses = (
  cidrStr: string,
  size: number,
  keyword = ""
): string[] => {
  keyword = keyword.trim();
  const parts = keyword.split(":");
  const result: string[] = [];

  if (
    parts.length > 8 ||
    parts.some((word) => !/^[\dA-Fa-f]{0,4}$/.test(word))
  ) {
    return result;
  }

  try {
    const cidr = new Address6(cidrStr);
    const startAddress = cidr._startAddress();
    const endAddress = cidr._endAddress();

    let addressNum = startAddress.add(BigInteger.ONE);

    while (addressNum.compareTo(endAddress) < 0 && result.length < size) {
      const { address } = Address6.fromBigInteger(addressNum);
      const shortedAddress = shortIpV6Address(address);
      if (
        address.includes(keyword) ||
        shortedAddress.includes(shortIpV6Address(keyword))
      ) {
        result.push(shortedAddress);
      }
      addressNum = addressNum.add(BigInteger.ONE);
    }
  } catch {}

  return result;
};
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @Alejandro The question is how to implement the function `getIpAddresses`. 

Comment: Let's start by showing your attempt and what problems have you encountered along the way.

Comment: @Alejandro Thx for your comment again, I've added my poor implementation above just now, and it is extremely slow because IPV6's total count is extremely large.

Comment: You seem not to understand how large something like a `/64` network is. An IPv6 `/64` network has 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 addresses, and at 1,000,000 addresses per second it will take over 584,542 **_years!_** to list them all.

Comment: @RonMaupin Yeah, that was a ipv4 mode `function` previously, and that’s why I’m here asking for a better implementation. I don’t need to list them all, I just want a tiny sub list which matched the `keyword`.

Comment: You still do not grasp the size. In your example, you need to iterate over 48 bits (16 bits for your example keyword from the 64 bits of the host portion), and that, at 1,000,000 per second, would still take nearly nine years to list all the addresses in the `/64` network that end in `1011`. There are 281,474,976,710,656 addresses that end in `1011`.

Comment: @RonMaupin Still, there is a limit `size` parameter, in that example, it only takes `10` addresses, we don't need the whole sub list.